# WPF Path Animation Error

Tags: c#, wpf

I have set up a storyboard to animate an ellipse along a defined path as shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743217.aspx, making a few modifications to suit my needs. However when I attempt to run my program, it gives me an AnimationException:

`Cannot animate the 'Center' property on a 'System.Windows.Media.EllipseGeometry' using a 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.PointAnimationUsingPath'. For details see the inner exception.`

The inner exception simply states: `Value does not fall within the expected range.`. I've never used storyboard before so I have no idea what to do here.

EDIT: Here's my code as it is. It's gone through some changes and I haven't taken out old comments yet, so accept as is.

```
        Location current = null;// locationEnum.Current;
        Point start = new Point();
        var segment = new PolyBezierSegment();
        foreach (var location in locations) {
            if (current == null) {
                current = location;
                start = new Point(current.X, current.Y);
            }
            else {
                //MessageBox.Show(location.X.ToString() + "," + location.Y.ToString());
                segment.Points.Add(new Point(location.X, location.Y));
                //current = location;
            }
        }
        //MessageBox.Show(start.ToString());
        var ellipseGeometry = new EllipseGeometry(start, 15, 15);
        var ellipsePath = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path {
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
            Data = ellipseGeometry,
            Margin = new Thickness(15)
        };
        cnvMap.Children.Add(ellipsePath);
        var animationPath = new PathGeometry();
        var figure = new PathFigure();
        figure.StartPoint = start;
        figure.Segments.Add(segment);
        animationPath.Figures.Add(figure);
        animationPath.Freeze();
        var animation = new PointAnimationUsingPath {
            PathGeometry = animationPath,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, ellipseGeometry);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(
            animation, new PropertyPath(EllipseGeometry.CenterProperty));
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        ellipsePath.Loaded += (sender, e) => {
            //MessageBox.Show("Horray");
            storyboard.Begin();
        };
```

Comment: Which modification caused the animation to fail?

Comment: Post your code, error to vague to help without it.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot solve your problem, but I can tell you how I would debug it:

- *Option 1*: Replace your code with something as close as possible to the example code you have linked (and which is expected to work). Then slowly start applying your changes until it no longer works. The last change you made is most likely the cause of the problem. If this doesn't help, post the code here, with both versions of the problematic line of code.
- *Option 2*: Tell Visual Studio to stop on all exceptions (Menu Bar/Debug/Exceptions) and try to catch the moment where the inner exception is thrown. Examine the Call Stack and the Local Variables window to find out *which* value is "outside the expected range".